# How do I place text under these two images

Tags: css, image

This is the part I am working with I want to include titles/text underneath the images of the record covers.

The CSS style

```
img
{
  float: right; 
  padding: 10px; 
  float: right; 
  text-align: bottom; 
}       

#box1
{
  height:220px; 
  width: auto;
  padding-left:20px; 
  border: none; 
}
#box2
{
  height:230px; 
  width: auto;
  padding-left:20px; 
  border: none;
}
```

My HTML code

```
<a href ="http://nervoustwitch.bandcamp.com/album/this-modern-world-ep"><img    src="modworldsmall.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://nervoustwitch.bandcamp.com/album/bad-reputation-ep"><img src="badrepep.jpg"></a>

<H1> Releases</H1>

<p>Nervous Twitch released <B>Bad Reputation</B> their 1st EP at the beginning of 2013.            Made up of tracks recorded the previous year, featuring previous band members and Erin on drums, the 'Bad Reputation' Ep used lo-fi production to good effect and featured 5 catchy, garage punk numbers most of which remain in the live set today</p>
<p>In June 2013 the band released <B>This Modern World</B>, with a  fuller sound the band continued to experiment with their songwriting style whilst maintaining their pop sensibilities.</p>

</div>
```

If you need to see more of the style sheet in order to answer my question please let me know.  Thanks

Comment: You are also missing <div> opening tag. what are #box1 and #box2, I guess they are div , Please write full code so that we can understand it better

Answer (score 0):

Got rid of the `float` on the images and put it on the `#box1` div instead. Added `text-align:center;` so that the text underneath would be centered.

[Here's and example](http://jsfiddle.net/9e2RL/1/). I put a border around the images so you could see them, since there is no source.